# How do I widen this data frame by removing the duplicates and adding frequencies of occurrences instead in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, data-manipulation

I have tried the following code, but the frequency column just gives me 0s and 1s. I want the actual count.

```
data2 <- as.data.frame(table(unique.data.frame(data))))
```

The data frame originally looked something like this (but large):

```
ID    Rating
12    Good
12    Good
16    Good
16    Bad
16    Very Bad
34    Very Good
```

I want this:

```
ID    Rating    Freq
12    Good      2
16    Good      1
16    Bad       1
16    Very Bad  1
34    Very Good 1
```

Comment: Do you want to make a histogram?

Comment: It will eventually go into a bar graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID, Rating) %>% tally()
```

and to automatically sort:

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Rating) %>% tally(sort = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `count()` function, and count by the combination of `ID` and `Rating`:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data_count <- count(data, c("ID", "Rating"))
> data_count
  ID    Rating    Freq
  12    Good      2
  16    Good      1
  16    Bad       1
  16    Very Bad  1
  34    Very Good 1
```

Comment: `count()` is in `dplyr` - you might want to be explicit about that as there is no base `count` function - `aggregate` in base does it too: `aggregate(list(Freq=dat$ID), dat, FUN=length)`

Answer (score 0):

The `unique` in the code gives the unique rows of the datasets, so the `table` output will be just '1' or '0' depending on whether the combinations are present or not.  Instead, we can apply the `table` on the whole dataset, and `subset` the "Freq" that are not '0'

```
 subset(as.data.frame(table(df1)), Freq!=0)
 #   ID    Rating Freq
 #2  16       Bad    1
 #4  12      Good    2
 #5  16      Good    1
 #8  16  Very Bad    1
 #12 34 Very Good    1
```